# Wedge products and Basis for the set of antisymmetric tensors

Tags: tensors, exterior-algebra

I just started studying Antisymmetric tensors. After introducing the antisymmetric tensors, the wedge product of dual vectors was defined. Then it was said that the set $\{e^i \wedge e^j\}_{i<j}$ is linearly independent and spans the space of all antisymmetric (r,0) tensors $\Lambda^2V^*$. The proof was left as an exercise in the book. The hint given in the book is - evaluate an arbitrary linear combination on an arbitrary tensor product $e_k \otimes e_l$.

To my understanding: $e_k \otimes e_l$ is a basis vector for $V \otimes V$, which would turn out to be the set of all (0,2) tensors. I can write a linear combination like this:
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i,j}c_{ij}e^i \wedge e^j
\end{equation}
But I'm not really sure how to do evaluate this on the tensor product $e_k \otimes e_l$ since the wedge product itself is made of tensor products. As far as I know, for $V\otimes W$,
\begin{equation}
(v\otimes w)(h,g)=h(v)g(w) \forall h \in V^*, g \in W^*.
\end{equation}
Evaluating a tensor product on another tensor product doesn't make sense to me. The book has mentioned no such thing.

So, please state the proof and explain these things in a way that I can understand. (I'm a physics student and not actually a math one.)

Comment: "But I can't think of how a tensor of $\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^{3*}$ or $\Lambda^3\mathbb{R}^{3*}$ would look like in the component form."
What do you mean by component form? (I know that in physics people tend to leave off the basis vectors and just write the components with the indices left out. Is this what you mean?) You gave the basis for $\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^{3*}$, so a general $(2,0)$ tensor on will look like a linear combination of these.

Comment: For your other question on how to evaluate the wedge product on the tensor:
$$e^i\wedge e^j (e_k\otimes e_l) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }(i,j)=(k,l)\\ -1 & \text{if } (i,j)=(l,k) \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
(depending on your definition of wedge product, you may have to normalize by a $\frac12$ or $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ somewhere)

Comment: @Keshav "$e^i\wedge e^j (e_k\otimes e_l) = 1$ if $(i,j)=(k,l)$, and $-1$ if $(i,j) = (l,k)$, and 0 otherwise." Please explain how.

Comment: How did you define your wedge product? One way I learned is to define $e^i\wedge e^j = e^i\otimes e^j - e^j\otimes e^i$. And tensors evaluate by multiplying:
$$e^i\otimes e^j (e_k\otimes e_l) = e^i(e_k)\cdot e^j(e_l) = \delta^i_k\cdot \delta^j_l$$
Is this how you defined it?

Comment: The wedge product definition is the same. But the book doesn't mention anything about how to evaluate a tensor product on another tensor product. So, that's what my confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

I will address:

> But I'm not really sure how to do evaluate this on the tensor product $e_k \otimes e_l$ since the wedge product itself is made of tensor products. As far as I know, for $V\otimes W$,
>   \begin{equation}
> (v\otimes w)(h,g)=h(v)g(w) \forall h \in V^*, g \in W^*.
> \end{equation}
>   Evaluating a tensor product on another tensor product doesn't make sense to me. The book has mentioned no such thing.

Here you have an element of $V\otimes W$ acting as a map $v\otimes w:V^*\times W^*\to \mathbb R$. You can check that this map is bi-linear, and a bi-linear map induces a map on the tensor product $V^*\otimes W^* \to \mathbb R$ by defining
$$(v\otimes w)(h\otimes g) := (v\otimes w)(h,g).$$
Note that this is well-defined because the tensor product properties exactly match up with the bi-linearity properties (e.g. $(h+k)\otimes g = h\otimes g + k\otimes g$, etc.).

(I think this "multi-linear map property" actually characterizes the tensor product -- I was looking for a specific Math SE answer which explained tensors and their universal property really well but couldn't find it, maybe someone knows what I'm talking about.) You should also play around with $(V^*)^*=V$ to get dual statements of the above.

Comment: Yes, it is bilinear. But, I don't understand how this reasons to inducing the map $V^*\otimes W^* \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Is there any other way to prove that set $\{e^i∧e^j\}_{i<j}$ is linearly independent and spans the space of all antisymmetric $(r,0)$ tensors $Λ^2V^∗$?

Comment: I think without knowing the book it's hard for me to say how they want you to prove it, but I don't know of a way besides using this to evaluate dual tensors on tensors.

Comment: It's Nadir Jeevanjee's 'An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists'.